Comedy designing city in desert
I cant remember the plot correctly, so there may be a few mistakes here.
The main character goes with father in law, who owns a big architect firm or construction firm, out into the desert to describe a city he envisioned to build. They talk, father in law says its a great idea, agrees with everything. After they get back, FiL shows the idea at the company and its completely diffrrent from what the MC had proposed. The city may have something like 'mesa' and the name of the desert/state in it. Dont remember what happens next, but eventually MC is invading the company and crawlingnon the ventilation, etc. Its a comedy movie, probably with over 5 years, since i saw it on tv some years ago. 
Whats the name of the movie?

That would be part of the plot for You, Me and Dupree. Michael Douglas is Mr. Thompson who is Matt Dillon's (Carl) boss and father in law. He (Carl) has a lovely vision of a great community friendly development. His semi tyrannical boss hijacks this into a grotesque new project palms at masa-vista or a very similar name.
This is a secondary plot to the main antics in the film which are Owen Wilson's great portrayal of unwanted house guest  Dupree.
Throw in Kate Hudson and we have a great comedy for all. Oh and yes there certainly is an office infiltration with someone falling through the ventilator shaft system at just the right time for comic effect.
